# Saving files in tree directory structure

Tags: c#, xml, azure

I have tons of XML files in the Azure Blob Storage. The files are saved in a tree structure. Having a root directory called QA, then in QA we have sub-directories for years [Eg :2015, 2016]. And inside each year folder there are sub directories for each month [Eg: 01,02, 03 ... 12]. Inside each month there are sub directories for each day.I have these xml files in these day folders.

I wrote a program to decrypt , unzip and process these xml files. I am using "useFlatBlobListing" property to list all blobs and process them.

But after processing the xml files  I want to store them in a new path but by creating diretories in the exact same way as they were for source files.

Folder Structure for Source Files

```
QA\2015\01\01\file1<datetimestamp>.xml
    -------01\file2<datetimestamp>.xml
    -------01\file3<datetimestamp>.xml
  ------\01\02\file1<datetimestamp>.xml
  ------\01\02\file2<datetimestamp>.xml
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ------\02\01\file1<datetimestamp>.xml
  ...
  ...
  ...
QA\2016\01\01\file1<datetimestamp>.xml
    -------01\file2<datetimestamp>.xml
    -------01\file3<datetimestamp>.xml
  ------\01\02\file1<datetimestamp>.xml
  ------\01\02\file2<datetimestamp>.xml
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ------\02\01\file1<datetimestamp>.xml
```

My Program:

```
var blobs = container.ListBlobs(prefix: InitialLocDir, useFlatBlobListing: true);  //Here the initialLoc is QA\
Console.WriteLine(blobs.Count());
foreach (CloudBlockBlob blob in blobs)
{
    FileName = blob.Uri.Segments.Last();
    blob.AcquireLease(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), null);

    MemoryStream sourceStream = new MemoryStream();

    blob.DownloadToStream(sourceStream);


    // Code - to decrypt-files//
    // Code to unzip and scrub the data//
// Do some updates/inserts using LINQ to XML.
    string finaldest = "NewFolderStruct/" + FileName;

     doc.Save(finaldest.xml); \\How to create the NewFolderStruct/ in exact same way ??
    // May be something like blob.UploadText(xDoc.ToString());
```

Comment: 2 questions: 1) Are you saving the scrubbed file locally anywhere on your computer? 2) Is it safe to assume that you would want to keep the same directory structure? May be you want to put processed file in another container?

Comment: No I am not saving anywhere locally. I would like to use the same structure Eg if the source xml is in QA\2016\01\01\  I would like to create the destination xml in  Safe\2016\01\01   where Safe is the new directory I want to create. Same container but different directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, here's what you would need to do:

- Since you mentioned that you're not saving the XML file anywhere on the disk, I am guessing that you're saving it in memory. What you need to do is create a `MemoryStream` kind of object for it. Let's call it `memoryStremForNewXMLFile`.
- Next you would create an instance of `CloudBlockBlob`. This is the one that will get uploaded in blob storage. Since you would want to keep the same folder structure but change `QA` directory to `Safe`, here's how you would create an instance of it:

  `var newBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blob.Name.Replace("QA/", "Safe/"));`
- Lastly, you would upload the stream to this blob.

  `newBlob.UploadFromStream(memoryStremForNewXMLFile)`

Please ensure to reset the position of `memoryStremForNewXMLFile` to the start of the stream otherwise your uploaded file will be of zero bytes.

Comment: after taking into a stream I have used the Stream reader to read the stream into a string   Eg: string xmlfile = reader.ReadToEnd();  and then I used Linq to xml to make changes.  Eg: var doc = XDocument.Parse(xlfile); and made changes to this doc object . Can I use something like newBlobUploadFromXdoucment(doc) ??

Comment: Unfortunately no. As David mentioned in his answer, you would need to use Azure storage SDK's blob upload methods which include uploading file, stream, byte array or text.

Comment: I converted the XDocument into a stream and did the UploadFromStream . The program ran successfully but I dont see the Directory with name Safe ?

Comment: Can you share your code? Put it in pastebin maybe or some other place?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. Can you check the value for the name of blob and newBlob? I'm guessing the issue is there only.

Comment: I am getting this error : An unhandled exception of type 'Starksoft.Aspen.GnuPG.GpgException' occurred in starksoft.aspen.dll

Additional information: gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

Thats with my decryption Initially I didn't have the problem when I tested the code to locally save the file.

Comment: Console.WriteLine(newBlob);
                Console.WriteLine(container.GetBlockBlobReference(blob.Name));

Both are printing : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob

Comment: As I have not worked with this library, I have no idea why you're getting this error. Sorry! Do this instead -  
Console.WriteLine(newBlob.Name). This should print the name of the blob.

Comment: Now I see the the newblob.Name and blob.Name are referring to same blob. So that is creating the error. The replace command didn't replace QA with Safe.

Comment: QA/2015/11/02/20151102114350.46400_Always_1446482614986.xml.gz.gpg
QA/2015/11/02/20151102114350.46400_Always_1446482614986.xml.gz.gpg


Both are referring to same one.

Comment: Note : var blobs = container.ListBlobs(prefix: InitialLocDir, useFlatBlobListing: true);

Over here the InititalLocDir value is "QA/"  ; is this the reason for not replacing ?

Comment: My bad actually! I went by your example and assumed the string I needed to replace is "QA\" where as what we really needed to replace is "QA/" (forward & backward slash). Sorry about this :(.

Comment: This worked in getting the right names : var newBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blob.Name.Replace("QA/", "Safe/"));

But somehow the error with gpg still exists, which I will try to resolve. Thanks for the great help gaurav

Comment: Can you also please tell me how to delete the extension in the filename ? eg : filename.xml.gz.gpg   I just want filename.xml.gz

Comment: Same way :) ... Do string.Replace(".gpg", "") in the newBlobName. HTH.

Comment: But I am already doing this : var newBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blob.Name.Replace("QA/", "Safe/"));

Where should I add that part ?

Comment: Try this: `var newBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blob.Name.Replace("QA/", "Safe/").Replace(".gpg", ""));`

Comment: Thanks a ton dude!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `doc.Save()` is (as it's not shown in your code) but you cannot use normal file i/o operations to create blobs or containers. For that, you need to use the Azure SDK (or REST calls) to create and upload your blob content (and to delete from original location, if that's what your app calls for).

Comment: to save the edits into a new xml on the blob storage I need an Azure SDK ? And yes I do have Azure SDK. Can you direct me how to proceed ? Also, I do not want to delete the initial file frm original location, I just want to place the processed file in different location but by creating the directories.

Comment: Yes - blob storage is not a file system (aside from File Service, but that's a different topic). And doesn't adhere to any type of file I/O commands. And you already have the Azure SDK (as you're using it in your sample code - that's where `CloudBlockBlob` resides).

Comment: Yeah, I have Azure SDK

Comment: Can you direct me how to proceed using that ?

May be by using blob.PutBlock(); ?